# Firefox extension -> get content of displayed tab

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I've a problem and honestly no clue how to fix it.

We have a little FF Extension as a little helper for daily work.
One Feature is to get a specific id from a ticket system.
It basicly works, but it does not refresh if there is more than one tab opened.

- tab 1: get ticket system id -> correct
- tab 2: Try to get id (different ticket opened) -> id from the first tab!

Function (is called when contextmenu-item is clicked):

```
otrs: function() {
        var source = '';
        source = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
        var position = source.search('OTRS#: ');
        var text = "[ ";
        for (var i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
            text += source[position+i];
        }
        text += ' ] ';
        if (text != '')
        {
            const gClipboardHelper = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboardhelper;1"]
            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboardHelper);
            gClipboardHelper.copyString(text);
        }
```

Maybe one of you may have a solution ;-)
Thanks in advance!

Martin..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to `source = gBrowser.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML;` this will work with the selected tab. you can target specific tabs like this: `source = gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[0].contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML;`

`gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[0].contentDocument` is tab 1

`gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[1]` is tab 2

`gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[2]` is tab 3 and so on

```
otrs: function() {
        var source = '';
        source = gBrowser.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML;
        var position = source.search('OTRS#: ');
        var text = "[ ";
        for (var i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
            text += source[position+i];
        }
        text += ' ] ';
        if (text != '')
        {
            const gClipboardHelper = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboardhelper;1"]
            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboardHelper);
            gClipboardHelper.copyString(text);
        }
```